# Ant XSLT 2.0 with saxon9 BUILD FAILED

Tags: debugging, xslt, ant, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have gotten this Ant script to work for XSLT 1.0 using the standard transform engine. However, I want to use XSLT 2.0 as well and I am running into a brick wall.

I have included the Saxon Jar and defined the factory class. When I run the script, I get a long pause (Maybe 10 seconds, way too much for my XSLT which is about 10 lines long) then I get a **BUILD FAILED:  Fatal error during transformation**

Any help would be much appreciated:

```
<project name="TranformXml" default="TransformFile">
    <target name="TransformFile">
        <!-- Transform one file into an HTML file -->


        <xslt in="input.xml"
            out="student.html"
            style="transform.xsl"
            processor="trax" force="true" classpath="./lib/saxon/saxon9he.jar">

            <factory name="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>

        </xslt>  

    </target>
</project>
```

I have tried a number of variations of this, including putting the  directly in the `<xslt>` element, plus toggling the `processor` and `force` options. Same problem every time.

(Note, I have tested my XSLT and XML in Oxygen and it works well there)

Thanks,

Casey

Comment: Start by editing your post to include a code-formatted list of the *actual* complete output from the Ant execution.

Comment: Without complete error message we can only guess...

Comment: Sorry guys. I should have been more verbose. I did find out why it was happening though. It was because I was not using resolve-uri() correctly.

Comment: Although, I am still getting a really long lag when I run the build, but there are no more errors.

Comment: It's great that you were able to answer your own question. Post the answer to your question, and then accept it as the answer to clear it from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1):

> Sorry guys. I should have been more verbose. I did find out why it was happening though. It was because I was not using resolve-uri() correctly.